# MassTransit 3 with RabbitMQ on IIS fails to authenticate

Tags: c#, iis, rabbitmq, masstransit

In the spirit of full disclosure, I'm uncertain whether this is a MassTransit/RabbitMQ issue or an IIS authentication/authorization issue, but now that you've been warned, here goes.  I have an ASP.NET MVC web application on a web server.  It's using the MassTransit.RabbitMQ 3.4 NuGet package to try to establish a connection to an application server with Rabbit 3.6.5 / Erlang 18.0 installed.  When the connection is trying to establish, IIS is throwing a 401.2:

```
HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.
```

I've disabled security on the app server, so my connection code from the web app looks like this:

```
return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                    if (virtualHost == "/")
                    {
                        virtualHost = string.Empty;
                    }

                    cfg.Host(new Uri($"rabbitmq://{hostName}/{virtualHost}"), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("qatemp");
                        h.Password("qatemp");
                    });
            });
```

I have set up the "qatemp" user on the app server and granted full access to all virtual hosts.  Note that I DO have a **working** C# console app that can successfully connect to the app server via the same code as above, so hence my concern that this is an IIS-specific issue.  Can anyone shed any light on this?  IIS is set up for windows authentication and that part seems to be working ok...I think.

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: Not sure why IIS having a 401.2 would have anything to do with MassTransit, if there were an error initializing the site you'd have a 5xx series error from a web server error.

Comment: This wound up being a Windows loopback issue.  The authentication issue only presents itself when accessing the website from the web server.  We purchased a new DNS entry and didn't add it into the registry as you're supposed to do to prevent this loopback issue.